# Tensor product of two simple modules

Tags: modules, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of arbitrary characteristic.
Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are finite dimensional $k$-algebras.
Let $S$ be a finite dimensional simple $A$-module and let $T$ be a finite dimensional simple $B$-module.
Is $S \otimes_k T$ simple as $A \otimes_k B$-module?

Comment: The answer is no. I give a counterexample for $k$ not algebraically closed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615711/tensor-products-of-simple-modules-over-algebras/1615841#1615841