# Tensor products of simple modules over algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be $\mathbb{C}$-algebras. Suppose that $M$ and $N$ are respectively simple $A$ and $B$ modules.

We can regard $M$ and $N$ as $A\oplus B$-modules in natural way, namely, $AN=0$ and $BM=0$. Let $M\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} N$ be the tensor product of $A\oplus B$-modules $A$ and $B$.

${\bf My\ Question:}$ Is $M\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} N$ still a simple $A\oplus B$-module? What conditions on $A$ and $B$ will make this result true? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: The premise of your question is incorrect; $M \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} N$ is naturally a module over $A \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} B$. Your proposed module structure forces the identity to act as zero. It's $M \times N$ which is naturally a module over $A \times B$.

Answer (score 3):

The following counterexample is available over a field $k$ other than $\mathbb{C}$. Let $A = B = M = N = L$ be a field extension of $k$. Then you want to ask (after the correction in the comments) whether $L \otimes_k L$ is a simple module over itself. For a commutative ring this is equivalent to being a field, but $L \otimes_k L$ is almost never a field. For example, if $L$ is a finite Galois extension, then $L \otimes_k L$ is a product of $\deg L$ copies of $L$.

When $k = \mathbb{C}$ we can attempt to use $L = \mathbb{C}(t)$ but I don't know off the top of my head what $\mathbb{C}(t) \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C}(t)$ looks like. Probably it's not a field either.

On the other hand, this is true if $A$ and $B$ are both finite products of matrix algebras over $\mathbb{C}$; for example, it's true if $A$ and $B$ are both group algebras over $\mathbb{C}$ of finite groups.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explain and correction. My question arose from a book which says that "Any irreducible representations of a direct sum of Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}_i$, can be considered as the tensor product of irreducible representations of individual summand $\mathfrak{g}_i$." I would be very grateful if you can explain this statement for me.

Comment: @user305813: that's a statement about Lie algebras, not algebras. To convert it into a statement about algebras you need to take $A$ and $B$ to be universal enveloping algebras, and the universal enveloping algebra functor $\mathfrak{g} \mapsto U(\mathfrak{g})$ takes direct sums to tensor products (that is, it acts like an exponential). In any case I'm not sure I believe that statement is true in full generality.

Comment: "*Probably it's not a field either.*" It's certainly not a field since its Krull dimension is one.

Comment: I agree with @QiaochuYuan that one would probably like some sort of smoothness condition on the representations.  I don't know what's known about (real) Lie algebras, but mention that Flath proves a result for admissible, irreducible representations of $p$-adic Lie groups:  http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=546596 .

Comment: If $k$ is not algebraically closed, then we can choose the extension $L$ as proper and finite-dimensional. The tensor product $L ⊗_k L$ is then not a field: the multiplication map $L ⊗_k L \to L$ is a surjective homomorphis of $k$-algebras, and it’s kernel, which is an ideal of $L ⊗_k L$, must be both non-zero and proper for dimension reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ and $N$ are finite dimensional, the tensor product $M \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} N$ is a simple module over $A \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} B$, and all simple finite dimensional representations of the latter are of this kind. This is Thm. 3.10.2 (pp. 56--57) of the book by P. Etingof et al (http://www.amazon.de/Introduction-Representation-Student-Mathematical-Library/dp/0821853511). Of course, the drafts of the manuscript have different numberings so the reference only holds for the published version. This was also posted as an intended answer for  [Tensor product of two simple modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756278/tensor-product-of-two-simple-modules), where I forgot to mention the algebraic closedness hypothesis on the field $k$.

Comment: When posting an Answer, even one month after the Question others have posted answers, you have the opportunity and responsibility to highlight for Readers where your solution differs from the previous posts.  Haste in posting is not much of a virtue, and in this case you back into a mention of an algebraically closed hypothesis that has not been related to the Answer you give.

Comment: For those who don’t have a copy of the book available: the statement is a direct consequence of Burnside’s theorem on matrix algebras, and presented as such in the book.